# Warning in knitr

Tags: r, knitr

I'm using `knitr 0.5` for my analysis and it throws this warning

```
Warning in parse_params(params) :
  (*) NOTE: I saw options " label = TrtScores-SD-Response, echo = FALSE, results = asis"
 are you using the old Sweave syntax? go http://yihui.name/knitr/options
```

for this chunck

```
<< label = TrtScores-SD-Response, echo = FALSE, results = asis >>=
R code
@
```

and `knitr 0.5` becomes very slow. Any idea to overcome this warning. Thanks

Comment: Well, I confess I'm mean -- I use `Sys.sleep(10)` when I see old Sweave syntax to make sure you see the warning clearly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You just need to add quotes around the results argument, like this:

```
<< label = TrtScores-SD-Response, echo = FALSE, results = "asis" >>=
R code
@
```

As documented at http://yihui.name/knitr/options (the web page to which the error message thoughtfully directed you):

> All option values, except the chunk label, must be valid R expressions just like how we write function arguments. For example, options that take character values must be quoted as you do in R (e.g. should write fig.path="abc" instead of fig.path=abc, and out.width='\textwidth' instead of out.width=\textwidth)

And then later on the same page:

> results: ('markup'; character) takes three possible values

See also the ["Transition from Sweave to knitr"](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/sweave/) page, which addresses this and other differences between Sweave and knitr. Like all of Yihui's documentation, it's excellently put together.

Comment: In fact you can also quote the chunk label as `label = 'TrtScores-SD-Response'`, and this is actually a slightly better practice, but I'm being lazy so I allow labels not to be quoted :)